# Index 2d arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

What is the best way to index the 2d arrays in Java? I want to use  these arrays in a cycle and how this will be possible?

```
 int [][] arr0 = {{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1}};
 int [][] arr1 = {{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1}};
 int [][] arr2 = {{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,0}};
 int [][] arr3 = {{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1}};
```

Or how can I use them like "`arr* [][]`" ?

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers, you could make an `int[][][]` or you could add all the items to a `List`; it's unclear how you want to iterate these elements. Can you expand on that please?

Comment: I want to use these arrays separately. I think I need to make list of them. How  should a List need to look like for these?

Comment: How should the output cycle? Do you get one value or three? Which values, in which order?

Answer (score 0):

Turn it to a 3-D array:

```
int[][][] a = new int[][][] {{{1,1,1},{0,0,1},{0,0,1}},
                            {{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{1,0,0}},
                            {{0,0,1},{0,0,1},{1,1,1}},
                            {{1,0,0},{1,0,0},{1,1,1}}};
```

If not, then use ArrayLists